# What's a good architecture for generating JavaScript from C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, architecture, code-generation

I have an set of objects in C# that are used to generate JavaScript. There is a Web UI where you choose a ton of options, this builds up a large object in C#. The object is then converted to JavaScript using a bunch of custom functions. This JavaScript is the core of our application, it is run server-side using the V8 engine.

Currently the JavaScript is actually generated on the client and it's a huge mess, impossible to test, difficult to maintain, etc. It uses a ton of for loops and string concatenation to generate the JS. I'd like to move this generation into C# and make it more testable. What are some good methods for generating this JS? Is string concatenation still my best option?

Comment: What kind of script are you generating?

Comment: it's code that runs on each hit going to our online store, does a bunch of eventing / analytics / reporting. there will be thousands of these little JS snippets that are run on each hit. i dont want to talk about it too much though because i work for a pretty big company and am still sort of new, not sure what i can and cannot say ;p

Comment: I think there is a serious flaw in your application architecture if you have to generate seperate Javascript code for each client.

Comment: the javascript isnt run on the client, it's run on the server. this is a massive application used by a large portion of forbes 50 companies, etc. youre just going to have to trust me that it's properly architected

Comment: @Shawn, I work on an app for a top 10 Fortune-500 company, I don't know what that has to do with application quality.

Comment: whatever man if you want to waste your time arguing with people on stackoverflow go ahead, but you didnt even read the question or dont understand it. "This JavaScript is the core of our application, it is run server-side using the V8 engine." "I think there is a serious flaw in your application architecture if you have to generate seperate Javascript code for each client."

Comment: @Shawn, I read the question.  Maybe I misinterpreted, but if the server side code has to be generated by the client, it sounds like you are generating unique code for each client, otherwise you would only need to generate the code once and store it on the server. The only thing I take issue with is your assertion that the architecture must be good because it is used by big companies. I'm not arguing about your architecture, I only gave my opinion based on the limited information you provided.  If my opinion is wrong, I'm sorry, this wasn't a personal attack on you.

Answer (score 2):

If the structure of the Javascript is extremely predictable (which I assume because it is possible for you to use string concatenation), you might be able to use a text templating language such as [NVelocity](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=nvelocity) or [DotLiquid](http://www.dotliquidmarkup.org/).  If it is completely unpredictable, you might need to generate a full [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), and generate the code from that.

Comment: i think this is the proper approach, ill check it out